# Error With gtk-launch: Unable to find terminal required for application

Tags: terminal, gnome, gtk, nvim

I tried to use the following command:

```bash
gtk-launch nvim file.txt
```

But it gave me this error:

```bash
gtk-launch: error launching application: Unable to find terminal required for application
```

How am I supposed to set the terminal required for application? I already set my `$TERM` and `$TERMINAL` environmental variables:

```
export TERM="kitty"
export TERMINAL="kitty"
```

Comment: why would you want launch a non GUI application with gtk-launch ?

Comment: I'm making a Dmenu script in which you choose a file and open it. The error message implies that the file would be opened in a separate terminal.

Comment: You are not launching dmenu with gtk-launch though are you? You are trying to launch nvim with it. I have a similiar function in zsh shell, ```find | dmenu | xargs -I {} nvim {} \;``` That's the basic idea. There's no requirement for gtk-launch , unless you want to launch a GUI app but nvim is not GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 18-09-2023: The list of hardcoded terminals [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/main/gio/gdesktopappinfo.c#L2685) is

```c
  static const struct {
    const char *exec;
    const char *exec_arg;
  } known_terminals[] = {
    { "xdg-terminal-exec", NULL },
    { "kgx", "-e" },
    { "gnome-terminal", "--" },
    { "mate-terminal", "-x" },
    { "xfce4-terminal", "-x" },
    { "tilix", "-e" },
    { "konsole", "-e" },
    { "nxterm", "-e" },
    { "color-xterm", "-e" },
    { "rxvt", "-e" },
    { "dtterm", "-e" },
    { "xterm", "-e" }
  };
```

### Solution 1

The first program on the list is a script which allows us to select an arbitrary terminal. So, a solution would be to install [this](https://github.com/Vladimir-csp/xdg-terminal-exec) script into `/usr/bin/xdg-terminal-exec` and configuring it. (On arch there is an aur package `xdg-terminal-exec-git`. I use Arch, btw)

To configure it, we need to create a file listing the terminals, in the priority order we want. The file should be `$HOME/.config/xdg-terminals.list`. For example:

```bash
echo kitty.desktop >> $HOME/.config/xdg-terminals.list
```

Then, we need to add the `.desktop` files to the data hierarchy of the script, the folder `$HOME/.local/share/xdg-terminals/`. For example:

```bash
ln -s /usr/applications/kitty.desktop $HOME/.local/share/xdg-terminals/
```

Now we can check if the terminal we wanted is opened by the command:

```bash
xdg-terminal-exec
```

with the previous example, this should open kitty.

Now `gtk-launch`, `exo-open`, `xdg-open`, `thunar` and all programs that use `glib2` to open `.desktop` files, marked with `Terminal=true`, should open in the desired terminal.

### Solution 2

A simpler solution would be to simply link the desired terminal into `/usr/bin/xdg-terminal-exec`. For example:

```bash
ln -s /usr/bin/kitty /usr/bin/xdg-terminal-exec
```

**Note:** This will only work if your terminal does not take a flag to receive commands to execute. If it does, you can use this script instead of the symbolic link:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh
$TERM [needed-flag] $1
```

Comment: Solution 1 is excellent! I hope that the proposal for `xdg-terminal-exec` will be accepted and becomes the default soon.

Answer (score 1):

The terminals are hard coded into gtk-launch. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/294430).

To hack around this, just do `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gnome-terminal /path/to/your-term`